# C# microsoft edge cookies folder path

Tags: c#, browser, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I created cookies from my site using ASP.net using different browsers and am able to read it from a windows application using C#.

But I am unable to figure out the path of cookies created from Microsoft edge in windows 10.

Please help!!!

Thank you!

Comment: This is not very programming related but you can just check the configuration of your browser (open the menus: `Edge -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Cookies` )

Answer (score 1):

The path for cookies in MS Edge can be found here : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC#!001\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies

(But that might change over time...)

You can use F12 to see cookies also, but it is dev friendly interface (no access to the local folder)

[image]

Comment: fwiw if you use the Developer Tools and then use the Network tab there is a button in the toolbar that looks like a cookie with a red x.  This will let you clear the cookies for that specific domain.